# while execute a powershell using service account getting unknown_user_type error

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I have one simple powershell script where i'm authorizing salesforce logic app connector.

When i execute script using service account credentials I'm getting below error -

```
Connect-AzureRmAccount : unknown_user_type: Unknown User Type
At C:\Users\test.ps1:34 char:5
+     Connect-AzureRmAccount -Credential $pscredential -Tenant $Tenant  ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Connect-AzureRmAccount], AadAuthenticationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.ConnectAzureRmAccountCommand
```

what is going wrong here any clue?

i'm executing below script to authorize salesforce connector api connection into azure logic app

```
Param(
    [string] $ResourceGroupName = 'ResourceGroupName',
    [string] $Subscription = 'Subscription',
    [string] $ConnectionName = 'ConnectionName',

    #Defines which Authorization type to authenticate the connector with.
    #AuthorizationTypes: 'ServiceAccount', 'ServicePrincipal'
    [string] $AuthorizationType = 'ServiceAccount'
)
#region mini window, made by Scripting Guy Blog
Function Show-OAuthWindow {
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

    $form = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Form -Property @{Width=600;Height=800}
    $web  = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser -Property @{Width=580;Height=780;Url=($url -f ($Scope -join "%20")) }
    $DocComp  = {
        $Global:uri = $web.Url.AbsoluteUri
        if ($Global:Uri -match "error=[^&]*|code=[^&]*") {$form.Close() }
    }
    $web.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = $true
    $web.Add_DocumentCompleted($DocComp)
    $form.Controls.Add($web)
    $form.Add_Shown({$form.Activate()})
    $form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
}
#endregion


$pscredential = Get-Credential
#You should not need to change this Id
$Tenant = Get-AzureRmTenant -TenantId "TenantId"

if ($AuthorizationType -eq 'ServiceAccount') {
    Connect-AzureRmAccount -Credential $pscredential -Tenant $Tenant -Subscription $Subscription
}
elseif ($AuthorizationType -eq 'ServicePrincipal') {
    Connect-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $pscredential -Tenant $Tenant -Subscription $Subscription
}
```

Comment: When you say ***service account***, do you mean service principal? If so, you need to use the `-serviceprincipal` switch and the credentials need to contain the app id and the service principal secret?

Comment: for service account i only execute like 
`Connect-AzureRmAccount -Credential $pscredential -Tenant $Tenant -Subscription $Subscription`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment, I suppose you want to login with a service principal, I can also reproduce your issue.

[image]

If you want to login with a service principal, you need to pass the `-ServicePrincipal` parameter.

You could refer to the complete script below.

```
$azureAplicationId ="<applicationId>"
$azureTenantId= "<TenantId>"
$azurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "<client-secret>" -AsPlainText -Force
$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($azureAplicationId , $azurePassword)
Connect-AzAccount -Credential $psCred -TenantId $azureTenantId -ServicePrincipal
```

[image]

---

**Besides**, I notice you use the old `AzureRm` module command `Connect-AzureRmAccount`. You should note the `AzureRm` module was deprecated and will not be updated anymore, so I recommend you to uninstall it and install the new [`Az`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-2.8.0) module. If you still want to use the old module, just change `Connect-AzAccount` to `Connect-AzureRmAccount` in my script.

Comment: thanks but its not Service Principle it is service account

Comment: @Neo Could you provide a link or explain what is the `service account`? Then I can look into it, not used it before.:-)

Comment: for service account script is - 
`Connect-AzureRmAccount -Credential $pscredential -Tenant $Tenant -Subscription $Subscription`

Comment: @Neo Hi, Neo, I know the script, but I am not sure what is the `service account` that you mean, could you let me know where did you use it or provide a related doc/link?

Comment: i'm trying to authorize azure salesforce connector API connection using the script. let me add full script into question.

Comment: @Neo Is the service account in the Azure Active Directory -> Users in the portal?

Comment: @Neo Does it have a format like `abc@xxx.onmicrosoft.com`?

Comment: @Neo If you just log in with `Connect-AzureRmAccount` without any other command, input the user account and password manually, will it work? I just want to confirm if the account is ok.

Comment: i checked yes it works fine and i got this as output after that -
Account          : myid@*.onmicrosoft.com
SubscriptionName : subname
SubscriptionId   : subid
TenantId         : tenantId
Environment      : AzureCloud

Comment: @Neo If so, I suppose the error is related to the `-Credential` parameter, could you try the new [`Az`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-2.8.0) module, uninstall the old module with `Uninstall-Module -Name AzureRM -AllVersions`, then install the new one `Install-Module -Name Az -AllowClobber`. I test it with `Az` module on my side, it works.

Comment: i need to change my full script with Az commands could you pls share any document for that

Comment: @Neo In general, just change the `AzureRm` to `Az` in the commands, like `Connect-AzureRmAccount` and `Connect-AzAccount`, `Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction` and `Invoke-AzResourceAction`. And if you don't want to change the original script, just run [`Enable-AzureRmAlias`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/enable-azurermalias?view=azps-3.3.0) before all your AzureRm commands, then you can run it directly.

Comment: @Neo And please pass the `Tenant-Id` directly to `Connect-AzureRmAccount`, it looks not good to run `Get-AzureRmTenant` before login.